# How can I prevent a GitHub action from running in parallel for the same branch, including pull requests?

Tags: github-actions

I have a GitHub action. It can be triggered from a branch, from a pull request, or manually. I want to achieve the following: There must never be two instances of this action running in parallel from the same branch, including pull requests from the branch.

My best idea is to do this (pseudocode):

```
concurrency: {{ if github.head_ref is nonempty then github.head_ref else github.ref }}
```

When the job is triggered from a PR, `github.head_ref` contains the name of the source branch. When the job is triggered from a branch, `github.ref` contains the branch name. So the above expression should solve my problem, except that it is not valid GitHub action code, and I cannot figure out whether it possible to make such an expression.

Can I write an expression or combination of expressions to achieve the above? Or can I solve my root problem in some other way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As suggested in the doc, in [this](https://docs.github.com/en/actions/using-jobs/using-concurrency#example-using-a-fallback-value) example, you could define a fallback/default value, so try with:

```
concurrency: 
  group: ${{ github.head_ref ||  github.ref }}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.

Comment: Thanks @Tyler2P I've added a bit of context

Comment: The syntax in this answer was incorrect; concurrency is an object with a property "group", and also, variables need a dollar sign such as `${{ some-variable }}`. I edited the answer.